# Use API keys using AJAX

Tags: ajax, api-key

I'm trying to get a user's API key from the database to perform URI calls.

At the moment I'm doing this in an unsecure way by running the following AJAX request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    async: false,
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/GiftRegistryAPI/api/v1/key/apikey/' + paramHostId,
    success: function(result) {
        var key = result.key;
        returnApiKey(key);
    }
});
```

The API key is stored in a global variable used by the methods that require it. 
What I need is

- Securely get the user's (host) API key
- Use the API key for the methods that require it?

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a php script that will store the API key. Then You will call this script as Your ajax call. The script will call API url directly and return data You requested.

Or You can pass Your key with ajax, but in this case You should bind Your API key to specific domains, which will be entitled to receive data.